# baseline image for ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, virtualbox

I am working on ubuntu over the virtualbox. I am running a setup that may have error or can not respond correctly when automate.

I want to create a baseline file for my ubuntu image so if something happens to my os it'll reset it to previous state.

**That is same as checkpointing or reseting in windows or other OS**

Kindly tell me how can i create a baseline for my ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Snapshot feature for this. (Or else if you create a clone at a preferred state, you can start a new VM from that state).

Comment: Thanks @Manula, But more i am thinking of working on the same server. if i clone or take snapshot i need to change the server again and again. insted of this i am hopping if there any thing like baseline so i can move my state to the fresh installed server when something bad happens to the server.

Comment: Well Thanks @Manula I guess you were right, This baseline i was looking for was the feature of virtualbox itself. where we can create or take snapshot of our current state and take backup in 'machine tool' in the "menu bar".